# Conflicting Javascript libraries with Fusion Charts and JQWidgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fusioncharts

So at work, I've been tasked with using two Javascript libraries (Fusion Charts and JQWidgets) to build a couple of web apps.

With Fusion charts, you have the ability to render charts in Flash or in Javascript. Our app updates the charts based on certain criteria through AJAX calls and all is fine when the charts are rendered in Flash. However, when rendering it Javascript, when the update method is called for the JQWidgets Grid component, it throws an error in one of the Fusion Charts included files.

I've chalked this up to conflicting method names in the respective libraries. After searching their forums, one of the moderators suggested re-writing the libraries "hooks." I am not a JS pro, and have no idea what that would entail. And if I'd even be capable of doing something like this. I was wondering if anyone had a similar experience, or could offer some advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please format your question.... A big block of text is hard to read :-(

Comment: Is it possible for you to share more information as to what exactly is conflicting? Right now the information is pretty vague unless I try and implement jqWidgets personally. It would help a lot if you can share screenshots, error messages and possibly a fiddle/code

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the order of the .js file inclusion.  Put first the one that it's currently below and vice-versa.